# Assign a unique number to duplicate items in a list

Tags: python

I made a program, but I not happy with the quantity of code. The end result is good, but I believe it can be made much easier, only I don't know how.

The functionality: If equal items > 1 in list, then assign all equal items a unique set number.  Below I made a unit test. I'm not happy with the class `CreatSet`. Can somebody advise me on how this can be implemented better?

```
import unittest


class Curtain(object):
  def __init__(self, type, fabric, number):
      self.type = type
      self.fabric = fabric
      self.number = number
      self.set_number = None

  def __str__(self):
      return '%s %s %s %s' % (self.number, self.type, self.fabric, self.set_name)

  def __eq__(self, other):
      return self.type == other.type and self.fabric == other.fabric

class CreatSet(object):
  def make_unique(self, original_list):
      checked = []
      for e in original_list:
          # If curtain: type and fabric is equal
          if e not in checked:
              checked.append(e)
      return checked

  def create_set(self, curtains):
      # Uniuqe items in list
      unique_list = self.make_unique(curtains)
      result = []
      for x in unique_list:
          # Create set list
          set_range = []
          for y in curtains:
              if y == x:
                  set_range.append(y)
          # Add set range into list
          result.append(set_range)

      # Create set number
      set_result = []
      set_number = 0
      for x in result:
          if len(x) == 1:
              set_result.append(x[0])
          else:
              set_number += 1
              for y in x:
                  y.set_number = set_number
                  set_result.append(y)
      # Return list ordered by number
      return sorted(set_result, key=lambda curtain: curtain.number)

class TestCreateSet(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
      self.curtains = []
      self.curtains.append(Curtain('pleatcurtain', 'pattern', 0))
      self.curtains.append(Curtain('pleatcurtain', 'plain', 1))
      self.curtains.append(Curtain('pleatcurtain', 'pattern', 2))
      self.curtains.append(Curtain('foldcurtain', 'pattern', 3))
      self.curtains.append(Curtain('pleatcurtain', 'plain', 4))
      self.curtains.append(Curtain('foldcurtain', 'plain', 5))
      self.curtains.append(Curtain('pleatcurtain', 'pattern', 6))
      self.curtains.append(Curtain('foldcurtain', 'pattern', 7))

    def test_auto_set(self):
      creat_set = CreatSet()
      result = creat_set.create_set(self.curtains)
      # Creating set
      self.assertEqual(result[0].set_number, 1)  # pleatcurtain, pattern
      self.assertEqual(result[1].set_number, 2)  # pleatcurtain, plain
      self.assertEqual(result[2].set_number, 1)  # pleatcurtain, pattern
      self.assertEqual(result[3].set_number, 3)  # foldcurtain, pattern
      self.assertEqual(result[4].set_number, 2)  # pleatcurtain, plain
      self.assertEqual(result[5].set_number, None)  # foldcurtain, plain
      self.assertEqual(result[6].set_number, 1)  # pleatcurtain, pattern
      self.assertEqual(result[7].set_number, 3)  # foldcurtain, pattern

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Ken Thompson, creator of Unix, has somewhat jokingly said that [spelling `creat()` without an "e" was his greatest regret](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8390979/1157100).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already implemented `Curtain.__eq__`, if you also implement [`Curtain.__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) you can use it as a dictionary (or [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)...) key, or a `set` member:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.type) ^ hash(self.fabric)
```

Now `make_unique` is trivial:

```
def make_unique(self, original_list):
    return set(original_list)
```

*(**Note**: if you require order to be retained, this will need additional work.)*

This also allows you to easily determine how many of each distinct `Curtain` you have:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(curtains)
Counter({<__main__.Curtain object at 0x02A15190>: 3, 
         <__main__.Curtain object at 0x031A0CF0>: 2, 
         <__main__.Curtain object at 0x031A0ED0>: 2, 
         <__main__.Curtain object at 0x0329EA30>: 1})
```

*(**Note**: implementing [`Curtain.__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) would make this more readable!)*

---

As pointed out in the comments, the `__hash__` implementation I suggest has an issue - if either attribute `type` or `fabric` is changed, the hash will be different. You could protect these attributes by making them "read-only" using properties:

```
class Curtain(object):

    def __init__(self, type, ...):
        self._type = type # note leading underscore on attribute

    @property # defining setter but no getter
    def type(self):
        return self._type
```

---

Alternatively, you can implement [`Curtain.__lt__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__) etc., then sort the list and use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to get your groups of "equal" `Curtain`s.

---

Either way, I would not implement `CreatSet` as a class, there's no need (as should be clear from the fact that there is no `__init__` and no class or instance attributes). Just have one class, and two functions:

```
class Curtain(object):
    ...

def create_set(curtains):
    ...

def make_unique(curtains):
    ...
```

Your code is generally compliant with the [style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (well done!) but you could do with some explanatory [docstrings](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

Comment: If `__hash__` depends on mutable attributes, one must take care not to change those attributes while the objects are in a `set` or `dict` keys. I think that is begging for trouble.

Comment: @JanneKarila that is a good point, I will edit to that effect

Comment: @Robert no problem. Note that if you make a `Curtain` hash-able, you can use Janne's answer using `x` as the key, rather than the tuple `x.type, x.fabric`.

Answer (score 2):

- Building the `set_result` list in `create_set` is not necessary, because the same objects are already in `curtains`. You can simply use

  ```
  return sorted(curtains, key=lambda curtain: curtain.number)
  ```
- It might be better not to return any value from `create_set`. That would highlight the fact that it modifies the objects in place.
- Here's my proposal for `create_set` that uses a `defaultdict` to accomplish both the detection of unique values and the grouping. However, your test will not pass because `defaultdict` is unordered, and therefore the numbers 1,2 and 3 can be assigned differently to the sets. If all you need are unique numbers, you could change the test not to expect an exact numbering. Note that this is a stand-alone function because there is no reason to put it in a class.

  ```
  def create_set(curtains):
      d = collections.defaultdict(list)
      for x in curtains:
          d[x.type, x.fabric].append(x)

      # Create set number
      set_number = 0
      for x in d.values():
          if len(x) > 1:
              set_number += 1
              for y in x:
                  y.set_number = set_number
  ```

Comment: thanks for solution, this code is better, cleaner and nicer. I can't click twice on the button finding the solving my problem. Both feedback are great.